# dynamic list of params to be permited in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am currently trying to permit params containing an array object.

```
#My controller
def students_params
  params.require(:student).permit(standards:[], subjects: [])
end
```

So here in my case, I will have a list of params names to be permitted.

Consider I have a constant which has list as below:

```
 STUDENTS_PARAMS = ['standands', 'subjects', 'grade', .....]
```

I tried doing this as below:

```
#My controller
def students_params
  params.require(:student).permit(*STUDENTS_PARAMS)
end
```

Problem here is params with array value and getting included.
Instead of adding all fields manually is there any other way, I can achieve this?

Thanks you

Comment: ```params.require```needs an argument which you arent providing in your example, so as it stands it would give you an ArgumentError

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you meant to say *Problem here is params with array value and **ARENT** getting included.*, which is to be expected because its looking for a hash not a symbol/string.

What if you try passing

```rb
STUDENTS_PARAMS = [{standands: []}, {subjects: []}, 'grade']

def students_params
  params.require(:student).permit(*STUDENTS_PARAMS)
end
```